# Automatically start reading another user's session -php,apache

Tags: php, apache, session

I am working on a user-login system in apache/php. On the time of login i am storing user_id into session variable

```
<?php session_start();
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password];
//checking if username and password correct in database
//if correct then 

$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
//$user_id is received from database ?>
```

After it on every page i am checking if session is true

```
<?php session_start();
if($_SESSION['user_id']==true){
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id];
```

`//other processing of page`}

then i am using this `$user_id` to fetch other content of user from database and display it.
It is working fine but some time when i am logged in with an account it automatically converted to another's account.

Can anybody help me in this.
Sorry for miss typing but i am using session_start at the top. And it is working file most of the time but some times it start reading others session values. I want to know how i can read others session value.????

Comment: yes, i am using it at top. but how it can read another's session automatically

Comment: Well, i have correct that "'" problem in password , now you have some suggestion bro, what is the problem

Comment: let me delete those comment first as you edited your question, than i will come back to you.

Comment: dear is hard to tell, you are getting $userid from the database, can you post that query and second then you are fetching data for more thing can you post that too. Than only i can help you as i dont know how you are getting your info from the database

Answer (score 0):

$_SESSION and session_start() are not conditional: you can't use them, as far as I know, to allow someone access based on a user/pass system.

A user gets a session ID the second he/she visits the site -- if the script has session_start() on top. If you want conditional session-control, I'd suggest writing one yourself (with a MySQL / PHP backend, for instance, to maintain active sessions).

This part of PHP is pretty misleading as $_SESSION is actually not the same type of session you want. $_SESSION is used to store temporary items for as long you're on the website and this information is stored in cookies or propagated via the URL. As soon as you close the tab or navigate somewhere else, the array is destroyed --  no more session data -- have to login again. Very impractical.

Comment: Do you mean that sessions are not secured?